# What does an Android StackView look like?

Tags: android, user-interface, stackview

Can someone provide a screenshot of an Android StackView that shows a potential application of this widget? I'm not sure what to use it for.

Answer (score 20):

There is one on [this page](http://www.broculos.net/en/article/android-101-how-create-stackview-widget).  Here's the screencap they display:

[image: StackView example]

An item flips off of the front, and onto the back (sort of like a deck of cards).

Answer (score 1):

There's an example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html) from the Android examples you can implement to see what it does. I suspect a screenshot may not be adequate enough since the widget inherits from `AdapterViewAnimator`.